# Two Android.mk use the same cpp files, any way to make another Android.mk don't recompile?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, native, ndk-build

I have two projects:

```
class
   *.cpp   
project1
   jni
   obj
   build.sh
project2
   jni
   obj
   build.sh
```

Two projects use the same cpp files, but when I build jni,they create two obj directory in project1/project2, any way to let another project don't compile again?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a directory for `NDK_APP_OUT` in your Application.mk?

Comment: I set NDK_APP_OUT to let them use one obj directory together,but it seems that cpp files still need to recompile when build another project.